# CPU usage for User tasks consuming up to 80%; 0% Idle. What does it mean?

Tags: macos, permission, cpu

I have noticed that my CPU usage is always near 100%.  0% of it is for Idle. About 20% average is for System tasks. The rest is going to User tasks (80%).  But if I look at individual tasks don't see anywhere near the 80%+ usage reported.  What is actually using this CPU?  Is it actually misreporting Idle?  I feel like this CPU consumption is at least partially real because my macbook is very sluggish.

[image]

I've tried checking `top` but the results are similar.

```
Processes: 196 total, 3 running, 5 stuck, 188 sleeping, 797 threads                                                                                                                            12:29:46
Load Avg: 9.63, 11.46, 13.58  CPU usage: 81.27% user, 18.72% sys, 0.0% idle  SharedLibs: 15M resident, 9044K data, 0B linkedit. MemRegions: 35083 total, 1542M resident, 81M private, 686M shared.
PhysMem: 6006M used (1012M wired), 1445M unused. VM: 467G vsize, 1065M framework vsize, 0(0) swapins, 0(0) swapouts. Networks: packets: 40509824/19G in, 43277118/14G out.
Disks: 8036430/96G read, 8249614/195G written.

PID    COMMAND      %CPU TIME     #TH   #WQ  #PORT #MREG MEM    RPRVT  
95931  top          11.2 00:02.85 1/1   0    29    37    2572K  2344K  
92843  Terminal     3.8  00:02.42 8/1   2    187   161   15M+   7856K+ 
0      kernel_task  2.6  07:17:27 101/4 0    2     1597  774M+  63M    
66037  WindowServer 1.1  00:33.09 6     2    334   1759- 65M-   32M-   
96-    TaniumClient 0.3  01:47:52 11    0    30    107   92M    92M    
74135- Microsoft Ly 0.2  02:57.89 27    2    675   694   73M    58M    
371    launchd      0.1  07:49.05 2     0    405   40    1444K  1384K
```

Comment: When was the last time you restarted this Mac?

Comment: You have 5 "stuck" applications. Get rid of those. Run the EtreCheck to get a  profile of your system. http://www.etresoft.com/etrecheck